# Why should I put JSON server responses under a `data` field for can.Model?

Tags: canjs, canjs-model

On CanJS.com, [it says not to return an array from a JSON service by itself](http://canjs.com/guides/Models.html#section_Talkingtotheserver). Instead, it should look like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {"id":1, "description":"Do the dishes."},
        {"id":2, "description":"Mow the lawn."},
        {"id":3, "description":"Finish the laundry."}
    ]
}
```

Why is this necessary, and does it only apply to Arrays or does it apply to all Objects? For instance, should a single object response look like this?

```
{
  data: {"id": 5, "createdAt": 2234234329}
}
```

Or if there's only one data item, is the `data` field no longer necessary? For example:

```
{
 "id": 5, "createdAt": 2234234329
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is primarily a security issue for JSON data sources.** Under ["Talking to the Server" on CanJS.com](http://canjs.com/guides/Models.html#section_Talkingtotheserver), it says:

> findAll will also accept an array from the service, but [you probably should not be returning an array from a JSON service](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/).

This links to a page about a [JSON vulnerability](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/) which explains that since an array-only response is considered valid JavaScript when loaded with `src` from a script tag, this can be used to expose secure data with an XSS-like attack. By namespacing your array, you're mitigating an attack.

CanJS will handle a plain JSON array response, but there's a security problem with array-only JSON responses. If you're only loading an individual data item, a single object will be fine. However, if you need to load a list, you need to use an Array somewhere so `can.Model.List` can process it correctly--putting it under a `data` key allows it to do so without creating a security risk.

Additionally, when you namespace your data properly, you can include other properties that will be loaded along with `can.Model.List` as mentioned in [asavoy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25976764/437226).

Answer (score 0):

For endpoints that return a single model instance, it's fine to return this:

```
{
    "id": 1, name: "bob"
}
```

For endpoints that return a list of model instances (and this is what the docs are referring to), the array is recommended to be kept under a `data` key. That way it will work automatically, and you can add pagination data more easily. Fields other than `data` will be added to the `can.Model.List` object.

```
{
    "data": [
        { "id": 1, name: "bob" },
        { "id": 2, name: "billy" }
    ],
    "page": 1,
    "totalPages": 10
}
```